# Json output maker for Bootstrap

Tags: json, twitter-bootstrap

Is there any way for make a **json output**(from all classess and arrays - **automatically**) for bootstrap like [Wordpress Json-Api](https://wordpress.org/plugins/json-api/) ?

Answer (score 0):

Use php and try with `json_encode`

eg:-

```
   <?php
   $arr = array('a' => 1, 'b' => 2, 'c' => 3, 'd' => 4, 'e' => 5);
   echo json_encode($arr);
   ?>
```